# Both Classic Search and SearchKit: "90150 records selected for export" - would this work in browser?

Tags: search, export, searchkit

It seems the only way of exporting some 90+ K contacts is via CLI.
I wonder, what would be a maximum number of contacts export threshold via GUI?

Comment: What is the Civi version

Comment: @PradeepNayak It's CiviCRM 5.69.2, but I think it was always this way - have issues running big imports in GUI years before.